# Stata: t-test with mean difference not equal to 0 in null hypothesis

Tags: stata

The hypothesis for my t-test is:

`H0: X1-X2=3
Ha: X1-X2!=3`

My code for running this t-test in Stata is `ttesti 52 12 5.1 57 8 5.1`,
which only applies to when the null hypothesis is `X1-X2=0`.

Is there any option command that I can use to specify the mean difference?

Comment: What about X1-X2-3=0?

Comment: That is, `ttesti 52 12 5.1 57 11 5.1` or `ttesti 52 9 5.1 57 8 5.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me post my comment (related with timat's comment) as an answer:

```
ttesti 52 12 5.1 57 11 5.1
```

This corresponds to transforming `X2` to `Z2 = X2+3` so that the null hypothesis is H0: E(X1-Z2)=0. This transformation is legitimate because sd(X2) equals sd(Z2). Alternatively you can transform `X1` to `Z1 = X1-3`, which corresponds to `ttesti 52 9 5.1 57 8 5.1`. In fact, any of the following works and gives the same result:

```
ttesti 52 12 5.1 57 11 5.1
ttesti 52  9 5.1 57  8 5.1
ttesti 52  1 5.1 57  0 5.1
ttesti 52  0 5.1 57 -1 5.1
```

or whatever as long as the mean differential is `1`.